# The generic type upper bound to be generic itself

Tags: java

I'm creating a generic interface and its class implementation. It's a disjoint set. The generic type upper boundary for this class is generic itself:

```
public class MyDisjointSet<K extends Pair<T, T>> implements IMyDisjointSet<K> {

}
```

and

`public interface IMyDisjointSet<T> {}`

but I get compile error `Cannot resolve symbol T`.

When I add a second parameter to the list of generic types it works compiles:

`public class MyDisjointSet<K extends Pair<T, T>, T> implements IMyDisjointSet<K>`

Why should we put T here? why not before class name?

Comment: `T` is not declared. What do you expect the types of `Pair` to be in this context? Do you want the type of set elements to also be the type of pair elements?

Comment: I think I get it now. There come as a list of generic types. Later types defining the earlier ones in the list.

Comment: It's rather common to have it as `MyDisjointSet<T, K extends Pair<T, T>>`

Comment: What do you mean, *"why not before class name?"* - when in Java do you ever declare a generic type parameter before the class name?

Comment: Or, you can try `K extends Pair<?, ?>`, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
public class MyDisjointSet<K extends Pair<T, T>,T> implements IMyDisjointSet<K> {
```